# Making java application as plugin to browser

Tags: java

i wold like to develop an java application which has to be embed in Browser, could you please let me know is there way??

Comment: Is the java-application installed on local pc, or is it an remote-java-application you like to connect to?

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to do this, but my recommendation would be to use the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). With the Google Web Toolkit, Java code is compiled to HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and is executed as a web app within the browser. While you can, in theory, use Java applets, they do not integrate well with native browser functionality, have undesireable security properties, and are much more commonly disabled (due to the potential security issues) than other types of browser functionality. Whereas Java applets definitely are not first class citizens in browsers, HTML/CSS/JavaScript are, so with the Google Web Toolkit, you can write in Java but have your code treated like a first class citizen in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

See [Applet](http://java.sun.com/applets/)

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/ 
this should help you out

Answer (score 1):

use JavaFX http://download.oracle.com/javafx/1.2/gettingstarted/javafx/index.html